# Is there a way to do something along the lines of "if message contains, do this"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm creating a Discord bot and want to reply if someone uses the prefix along with an unknown command. What would be the "contains" function?

```
switch(message.content){
          case '$status':
              message.reply('Online and ready to go!');
            break;
            case 'ping':
                message.reply('Pong!');
              break;
              case '$help':
                  message.reply('$status - reply \'Online and ready to go!\'');
                  message.reply('$despacito - reply with despacito');
                break;
                case '$despacito':
                    message.reply('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D-KIbiaWsAAV1-2.jpg');
                  break;
                  default: 
                  console.log('not recognized:' + message.content);
```

I'd want to add the `If *contains* '$', message.reply('Uh oh, looks like that's not a valid command.')` function right after the console.log.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for includes - message.content.includes(...)

Answer (score 0):

The current way your code is written, rather than using [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) which would search for your prefix *anywhere* within the string, you can use [`String.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to see if the message *starts* with the prefix.

```js
// const prefix = '$';

default:
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    return message.channel.send('Unknown command.')
      .catch(console.error);
  }
```